# Angular 4 Subscribe method call multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, typescript2.0

im creating a global modal component.
My problem is when i call the subscribe method it call multiple times base on the number of the modal was called.
How can i prevent mutiple calls on observable subscribe method? Please check my code below. Thanks in advance.

**modal.model.ts**

```
export class Modal {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  visible: boolean = false;
}
```

**modal.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Modal } from './modal.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  static readonly YES = 1;
  static readonly NO = 0;

  private modal = new Modal();
  private subject = new Subject<Modal>();
  private action = new Subject<number>();

  confirmationDialog(message) {
    this.modal.title = 'Confirmation';
    this.modal.message = message;
    return this;
  }

  show() {
    this.modal.visible = true;
    this.setModal(this.modal);
    return this;
  }

  setAction(action: number) {
    this.action.next(<number>action);
  }

  getAction(): Observable<any> {
    return this.action.asObservable();
  }

  setModal(alert: Modal) {
    this.subject.next(<Modal>alert);
    return this;
  }

  getModal(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**modal.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalService } from './modal.service';
import { Modal } from './modal.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  public modal: Modal;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.modalService.getModal().subscribe((modal: Modal) => {
      this.modal = modal;
      console.log(modal);
    });
  }

  no() {
    this.modalService.setAction(0);
    this.modalService.close();
  }

  yes() {
    this.modalService.setAction(1);
    this.modalService.close();
  }
}
```

**calling the modal component**

```
showModal() {
  this.modalService.confirmationDialog('Are you sure you want to save this record?').show();
  this.modalService.getAction().subscribe(response => {
    if(response === ModalService.NO) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('call mutiple times');
  });
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the output on the console log.
[console log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT2kb.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think i would be easier to use the **async** pipe inside your modal component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ModalService } from './modal.service';
import { Modal } from './modal.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent {
  public modal$: Observable<Modal>;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService){
      this.modal$ = this.modalService.getModal();
  }

  no() {
    this.modalService.setAction(0);
    this.modalService.close();
  }

  yes() {
    this.modalService.setAction(1);
    this.modalService.close();
  }
}
```

and inside your template for example:

```
(modal$ | async)?.title
```

This ensures that Angular is cleaning up the subscription by itself on component destruction.

For your subscription when creating the modal you can use the `take` Operator, which completes the subscription if x values where emitted.

```
this.modalService.getAction().take(1).subscribe(response => {
    if(response === ModalService.NO) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('call mutiple times');
});
```

I'm assuming you only want 1 value (as its a simple dialog).

Comment: Maybe your application has not all operators imported, you could import the operator with: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Comment: Thanks, your  code is working, the take() method did the trick. However the modal will popup if i click the button  twice. any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Just don't forget to unsubscribe modalService when your component is destroyed.. eg.

```
...
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public modal: Modal;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService){}

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.modalService.unsubscribe(); // or something similar
  }
}
```

What's could be happened is that every time you open the modal the subscription keeps persisted and will be executed +1 time, but using destroy when the modal is closed or destroyed, you'll be removing the subscription as well.

Or even better, basically every time you subscribe you're creating a new observable, but you could reuse the first one you create, applying a simple validation (heads up, you shouldn't use unsubscribe in this case). eg.

```
if (this.modalService.getModal().observers.length === 0) {
    this.modalService.getModal().subscribe((modal: Modal) => {
        this.modal = modal;
        console.log(modal);
    });
}
```

There's many ways to prevent triggered subscribers more than once.

Comment: The second method  is showing error ,type  Observable<any>  does not have property observers.

Answer (score -1):

Move your subscribe to the ctor. Ex:

```
    private unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(private modalService: ModalService){
        this.modalService.getModal()
          .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
          .subscribe((modal: Modal) => {
               this.modal = modal;
               console.log(modal);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
         this.unsubscribe.next();
         this.unsubscribe.complete();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but still not working.

Comment: Subscribing inside a component constructor without cleaning it up inside the ngOnDestroy lifecyclehook or via `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` is a bad practice.

Comment: it was more to troubleshoot his multiple subscribes firing. anyway, good point. updated.