# Angular4 is replaying my requests on timeout

Tags: angular, request

I have a very long request (it is a batch) which lasts more than 5 minutes.
When I start a request with my Angular4 application, the framework is replaying the request several times, probably because it triggers a time out.

Do you have any solution to that problem ?

When launched out of my Angular application, the request finishes and is not replayed. This is really due to the framework.

Here is my configuration, that I cannot change, because work and stuff... :

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
```

Please help, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Related issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327850/angular-4-subscribe-method-call-multiple-times

Comment: Another related issue ? https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people dealing with this issue, it is due to HTTP 1 behind a company proxy.

See this post for more information :
https://blogs.oracle.com/ravello/beware-http-requests-automatic-retries